# Android Volley gives timeout exception

Tags: android, android-volley

i tried a lot to fix volley timeout exception in Android. 
I tried to used that retry policy but its not working.
It comes timeout error but request get send properly but don't get response.

Comment: _i tried a lot_ show us what have you tried a lot.

Comment: There are two time outs. Request timeout and response timeout. in your case there might be prob with server.

Comment: add your work you did?

Comment: Put your code then we can help you

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can test your Code by using Requestbin
Click [here](https://requestb.in/).
It will give you a demo URL that you can hit from your code and check is you server not responding or anything else went wrong.